# Ionic 2: displaying issue on IOS

Tags: ios, angular, ionic2

[SEE ISSUE](https://giphy.com/gifs/xUA7bbIuTambPVf6ik/fullscreen)

I am building an Ionic 2 app with Angular 2. I have an issue only on one page of my app only on IOS. Only the visible part of page is loaded ([SEE ISSUE](https://giphy.com/gifs/xUA7bbIuTambPVf6ik/fullscreen)). Someone already had this kind of displaying issue and know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the background image. 
To fix my problem i used `<preload-image>` instead of `<background-image>`.